# dateTime difference income calculation

Tags: php

I have the following code which shows me the difference between two dates. now i would like to calculate my income based on that difference with a base rate of 8$ per hour but i haven't managed doing this because of the way dateTime returns me the difference. any ideeas?

```
$lastUpdate = new DateTime($lastUpdate['lastUpdate']);
$currentTime = new DateTime("2013-03-24 19:45:55");
$interval = $lastUpdate->diff($currentTime);
echo "difference " . $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days " . $interval->h . " hours " . $interval->i . " minutes " . $interval->s . " seconds";
```

Comment: So tell us about the problem with the way a DateInterval is returned? You're not really explaining very well

Comment: well i have something similar as mysql solution where i have the difference between two dates and it updates a field based on the income per second and i would like to do the same thing in php. i found the difference but i don't know how to calculate the income/format the date the same way mysql handles it.

Comment: ($interval->$interval->format('%a') / $hoursPerDay * $baseRate) + $interval->$interval->format('%h') * $baseRate;

Answer (score 2):

Get total seconds from diff, divide them on 3600 and multiple on your rate.

Try something like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#102271

Just a part of code from here to give you an idea:

```
  //...
  public function to_seconds() 
  { 
    return ($this->y * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($this->m * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($this->d * 24 * 60 * 60) + 
           ($this->h * 60 * 60) + 
           ($this->i * 60) + 
           $this->s; 
  } 
  //...
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to convert to seconds and multiply by `8/3600`

```
$lastUpdate  = new DateTime($lastUpdate['lastUpdate']);
$currentTime = new DateTime("2013-03-24 19:45:55");
$interval    = $lastUpdate->diff($currentTime);
//generate time string
$timeStr     = "";
if($interval->y >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->y ." year"   .($interval->y==1 ? " ": "s "); }     
if($interval->m >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->m ." month"  .($interval->m==1 ? " ": "s "); }      
if($interval->d >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->d ." day"    .($interval->d==1 ? " ": "s "); }
if($interval->h >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->h ." hour"   .($interval->h==1 ? " ": "s "); }
if($interval->i >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->i ." minute" .($interval->i==1 ? " ": "s "); }
if($interval->s >0) { $timeStr .= $interval->s ." second" .($interval->s==1 ? " ": "s "); }
//add up all seconds
$seconds = ($interval->y * 365* 24 * 60 * 60)
         + ($interval->m * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
         + ($interval->d * 24 * 60 * 60)
         + ($interval->h * 60 * 60)
         + ($interval->i * 60)
         +  $interval->s;
//multiply by your wage (in seconds)
$hourly_rate = 8.00;
$pay         = ($seconds * $hourly_rate)/3600;
$pay         = round($pay,2,PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP); //round to nearest cent
//print out the resulting time, rate & cost statement
printf("Total time of %sat hourly rate of $%.2f equates to $%.2f\n",$timeStr,$hourly_rate,$pay);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont use strtotime for your purpose

```
$lastUpdate = strtotime($lastUpdate['lastUpdate']);
$currentTime = strtotime("2013-03-24 19:45:55");
$interval = ($currentTime - $lastUpdate)/(3600);
$interval = round($interval,2);
$income   = $interval*8;
echo $interval."hours";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be pretty, you'll need to keep what you have there and calculate some new variables.

```
$years = $interval->y * 365 / 24; // give it that it's not a leap year 
$months = $interval->m * 730; // approximation of how many hours are in a month
// ... so on
$grandSummation = $years + $months + $days + $hours + $seconds; 
$finalBaseApproximation = $grandSummation * 8; 
echo "Your income is $" . $finalBaseApproximation;
```